# Arch using Deepin desktop does not show pop ups properly

Tags: arch-linux, deepin

I have just installed Arch with the Deepin desktop and whenever it shows a popup it only shows a blurry transparent box. Some of these boxes are interactive, I can move them around, click on buttons inside them and right click them to bring out more options. However I can not see anything they are saying, there is nothing but a blurry transparent box.

The first image shows a popup window that appeared when I double clicked on another Disk in my computer, trying to mount it. Probably some sort of error message.

[image: Popup that probably says mounting not allowed]

The second image is after I right clicked the popup above. There is a second, smaller menu popup that is also transparent. However the contents of this menu show up at the top left corner of the screen. For some reason the contents are disconnected however I am happy that they at least appeared somewhere on the screen.

[image: Right clicking the pop up window is also bugged]

Whats weird is that this doesn't affect all popups, this third image has both a working popup and a not working one (below the working one). When I press the Recognize button I assume it is supposed to display a popup that has the name of the monitor however when I do that all I see is a transparent box.

[image: one popup window that works and one that doesn't]

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: having the exact same problem in DDE via Arch-based RebornOS. I intend to visit the RebornOS discord server to see if there is any help for this and I'll be happy to report back here should I learn anything. If you learn anything outside of this present Stack Exchange thread, please funnel it back here for me as well! Best wishes!!!

---

---

---

---

---

[WAY TOO] LONG VERSION:

I am having the -EXACT- same issues with a RebornOS Deepin install. Tried it on two different machines with the same results across both. In addition to this, I'm also having an issue where items will not appear on, or allow to be pinned to the taskbar at the bottom of the screen.

This is my first time trying Deepin in an Arch-based environment. I've seen several Arch-based distros initially have, and then later remove Deepin ISOs from their list of variants, and have heard rumblings from various sources all saying something to the effect of "the Deepin experience is just not there yet in Arch".

While it's too soon for me to say for sure that I either agree or disagree with that assessment, and certainly hope someone or something will be able to prove it wrong for us, I have to admit that I'm really starting to fear its veracity. Perhaps a solid, enjoyable Deepin experience within Arch is just not a present reality yet. Which would be truly unfortunate, as it and UKUI on Arch are the top two combinations I want to explore right now (I'm trying to decide whether I prefer DDE or UKUI, but would love to have the underpinning of Arch with each).

By the way, though I won't spend much time on this since it's super tangential [at best], there is also a RebornOS UKUI option, and I'm having different, but equally frustrating problems with it (mostly related to scaling not seeming to work right). I've also heard similar concerns about UKUI in Arch and have heard of distro spins disappearing for it as well.

I have had great experiences with Arch otherwise, though, with Garuda KDE Dr460nized Gaming Edition being just spectacular so far on my main "big rig" gaming PC, Manjaro Xfce (configured to look like Windows 95) running great on my secondary laptop with a failed attempt at adding NsCDE being the worst thing that has happened to me there, and of course, SteamOS on the Steam Deck also having been a largely satisfying experience.

But so far, Reborn has been a disappointment - with the MASSIVE caveat that it might not be Reborn's fault at all, but perhaps there is some truth to the fault being at the intersections of Deepin / UKUI and Arch. You know, if I went for KDE or Gnome on Reborn, it might be simply incredible. But I'm not a big fan of Gnome, and already have three active installs of KDE (the two mentioned above plus Ubuntu-based KDE Neon on my main laptop). I love KDE. It's my "main DE"....but I'm really wanting to explore something else, and it's DDE / UKUI on the "beautifully modern" side, and NsCDE on the quirky retro side that most capture my fascination / attractio / imagination. So right now, the only thing really drawing me to Reborn specifically is that it offers UKUI and Deepin right out of the box without having to manually install them. You know, great as it would probably be, I just don't think I have any use for a RebornOS KDE install right now.

I suppose I'll give it a little more time, and maybe drop in on the RebornOS discord server (which does offer support - and I'll be happy to funnel that back if I learn anything of value that might apply outside of Reborn). But ultimately, if this is just what to expect here, I'll keep Garuda and Manjaro and SteamOS, but probably drop Reborn in favor of "straight Deepin" and either "Ubuntu Kylin" or even "OpenKylin" until I can decide once and for all whether I personally prefer DDE or UKUI.

Cheers!

Comment: I am glad you want to help, but this is not a solution to the problem. If you find out anything and report back, that is great, but a SE answer is not a place for "I have the exact same problem" _comments_, that is literally for comments.

Comment: I am a Stack Exchange newbie, and never realized there was even a distinction to be had here. I will note that for the future. In the meanwhile, I will still post back if I learn anything.